# Group by the file by 1st coulmn

Tags: shell, unix, awk

I have comma seperated 3 filed file, i need to group the file based on the 1st coulmn.
Based on 1st filed, if there are more than 1 rows are having same 1st column value i need to group the 2nd and 3rd column values together based on the 1st column

Sample Input

```
aplple,shop1,11
aplple,shop2,11
orange,shop7,22
pine,shop8,23
pine,shop9,23
pine,shop11,23
pine,shop15,23
```

Expected Output

```
aplple
11
shop1
shop2
orange
22
shop7
pine
23
shop9
shop11
shop15
```

Comment: Will the first and third columns always match up? That is: Will a line with `aplple` in the first field always have `11` in the third field, etc.?

Comment: @Marjer Do you know about (1) awk's associative arrays and (2) the `END` target? Associative arrays are indexed by a string, the `END` target allows awk to process all the data collected scanning the file when the end of file has been reached.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one `awk` solution:

```
awk -F, '{print ($1!=prev?$1RS$3RS$2:$2);prev=$1}' file
aplple
11
shop1
shop2
orange
22
shop7
pine
23
shop8
shop9
shop11
shop15
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk solution

```
awk -F, '{x=a[$1" "$3]=a[$1" "$3]?x"\n"$2:$2}END{for(i in a){split(i,b," ");print b[1] RS b[2] RS a[i]}}' file
```

or this

```
awk -F, '{x=a[$1"\n"$3]=a[$1"\n"$3]?x"\n"$2:$2}END{for(i in a){ print i RS a[i]}}' file
```